# Animate from one style to another

Tags: wpf, animation, triggers, styles

Just wondering if anyone know how to animate from one style to another i.e. going from NormalStyle to ActiveStyle when the user focuses on the textbox

```
<Style x:key="NormalStyle" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Gray" />
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="2" />
</Style>

<Style x:key="ActiveStyle" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}" BasedOn="{StaticResource NormalStyle}">
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Green" /> 
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="4" />
</Style>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to swap the whole style, I think you might have to do it in code:

```
<StackPanel>
    <TextBox Style="{StaticResource NormalStyle}" GotFocus="TextBox_GotFocus" LostFocus="TextBox_LostFocus"/>
    <TextBox Style="{StaticResource NormalStyle}" GotFocus="TextBox_GotFocus" LostFocus="TextBox_LostFocus"/>
</StackPanel>
```

```
    private Style focusedStyle;
    private Style normalStyle;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        focusedStyle = FindResource("ActiveStyle") as Style;
        normalStyle = FindResource("NormalStyle") as Style;
    }

    private void TextBox_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ((TextBox)sender).Style = focusedStyle;
    }

    private void TextBox_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ((TextBox)sender).Style = normalStyle;
    }
```

Otherwise, you are pretty much confined to triggering back and forth..

```
<TextBox Text="1" >
        <TextBox.Style>
            <Style BasedOn="{StaticResource NormalStyle}" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="GotFocus">
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard>
                                <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush.Color" To="Green" Duration="0:0:0.1" />
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </EventTrigger>
                    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="LostFocus">
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard>
                                <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush.Color" To="Gray" Duration="0:0:0.1" />
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </EventTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </TextBox.Style
```